# Remove tag after hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code to add line to my submenu :

```
$("li.mega-menu-megamenu a").hover(function(){ 
    $( "<div class='remove'><hr /></div>" ).insertAfter("#mega-menu-primary-2 li:last-child" );
});
```

Its working perfectly fine.But the issue is that I want to remove that tag when there is no hover.

I have tried this : `$("li.mega-menu-megamenu a").unbind('hover');` But by doing this, it will not add html tags at all.

How can I remove line when there is no hover on menu ?

Comment: Wanna `remove tag` or either `remove class`

Comment: @Twix Are any of the answers below correct? Click the green checkmark to select one.

Comment: Nope..None of those meet my desired result. Some of them do, but they are buggy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseout event for that

```
$("li.mega-menu-megamenu a").mouseout(function() {
    $(".remove").remove();
});
$("li.mega-menu-megamenu a").mouseenter(function() {
    $("<div class='remove'><hr /></div>").insertAfter("#mega-menu-primary-2 li:last-child");
});
```

Another possible solution is, instead of adding and removing the element you can just hide/show it.

```
$(document).ready(funnction() {
    $("<div class='remove'><hr /></div>").insertAfter("#mega-menu-primary-2 li:last-child");
    $(".remove").hide();
    $("li.mega-menu-megamenu a").mouseout(function() {
        $(".remove").hide();
    });
    $("li.mega-menu-megamenu a").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".remove").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Twix can you share the html Or create a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for hide/show so you don't keep adding/removing from the DOM.

```
// Add the element to the DOM once and then hide it
var $removeElement = $( "<div class='remove'><hr /></div>" )
    .insertAfter( "#mega-menu-primary-2 li:last-child" )
    .hide();

// On mouseover we show the $removeElement and mouseout will hide it
$("li.mega-menu-megamenu a")
    .hover(function(){ $removeElement.fadeIn();  },
           function() { $removeElement.fadeOut(); }
     );
```

I used fadeIn/fadeOut but you can use show/hide instead if prefered.

Comment: strange ..Its not working.When I inspect, The tag is not included  :(

Comment: @Twix Your selectors are probably not selecting the proper elements in the DOM. You'll need to post some more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 2 functions to hover. Second will be called when mouse is exiting the element.

```
$("li.mega-menu-megamenu a").hover(function() {
  $("<div class='remove'><hr /></div>").insertAfter("#mega-menu-primary-2 li:last-child");
},
function() {
  $(".remove").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$('li.mega-menu-megamenu a').on({
    'mouseenter':function(){
       $("<div class='remove'><hr /></div>").insertAfter("#mega-menu-primary-2 li:last-child");
    },'mouseleave':function(){
        $(".remove").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply !Its working .But it will remove line on mouse leave.I have large submenu.So when I go to the submenu item, line gets dispperead. I want line to be there till submenu is open.

Comment: Need to use stopPropagation() for your submenu's.

Comment: Can you guide me for that ?

Comment: `$('.yoursubmenu').function(e){(e.stopPropagation();)};`

Comment: @Twix: but you know why you need `stopPropagation()` right?

Comment: @Benjamin I added `$('#mega-menu-primary-2 li ul').function(e){(e.stopPropagation();)};` When I add that line , line is not added to sub menu.

Comment: @TomSarduy I have gone through jQuery Docs so Now I know the use of that :)